# One Vita = One PSN account, what about games?

Tags: ps3, psn, ps-vita

I know you about the relation 1 PS Vita = 1 PSN account = 1 memory card*
*Actually, you can swap accounts after restoring the device and all that...

What I am not so sure is if I can download Vita games from a secondary account in my PS3, and then send it to my Vita. In other words:

2 PSN accounts both linked in two PS3 >> Both PS3s can send games to Vita

I know it's a bit confusing but it's also hard as hell to explain. :S

Comment: So in essence you want to know how to send games from 2 different PS3s with different PSN accounts to your PS Vita?

Comment: Yes, or if it is even possible. I'm afraid if a game is linked to account A, it won't transfer to Vita linked with game B. But I wanted to confirm.

Comment: As far as my research goes it is not possible to send games across accounts. But I have not found an official source.
The best options seems to be swapping accounts as you described with two memory cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can not do what you are hoping to do.

Only the PSN account on the PS3 that is also the PSN account signed into the Vita can send games to it. If you want to send games from the other PSN account you will need to wipe and reset the Vita to the other account first.